# Why method main is not work after adding code connection elasticsearch (java)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to create a main method into my class in order to test connection with elasticsearch engine

so I want inside my constructor getConnection of object TransportClient of elasticsearch

this is my code where I want just to test that my connection with elasticsearch is fine

(when I remove the part code of elasticsearch it work but when I add it I have this error)

```
Exception dans l'unité d'exécution "main"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 version supérieure incorrecte; classe=org/elasticsearch/common/transport/TransportAddress, décalage=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:274)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:985)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:416)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:652)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:346)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:618)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)


    public class EsConnectionManagerBiz {


        private String host;
        private int port;
        private String clusterName;


        public EsConnection(String host, int port, String clusterName) {
            super();
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.clusterName = clusterName;

        }

        public EsConnection() {
            this.clusterName="elasticsearch";
            this.port=9300;
            this.host="localhost";
           System.out.println(this.clusterName);
// probleme code start
           InetSocketTransportAddress node;
       try {
           node = new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(this.host), this.port);
           // settings elasticsearch
           Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", this.clusterName)
                   .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
           TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
           client.addTransportAddress(node);
           System.out.println("================== " +client+" ========");
       } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    // end
        }


        public String getHost() {
            return host;
        }

        public void setHost(String host) {
            this.host = host;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return port;
        }

        public void setPort(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        public String getClusterName() {
            return clusterName;
        }

        public void setClusterName(String clusterName) {
            this.clusterName = clusterName;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new EsConnection();

        }
    }
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It's difficult to understand the error because it's in French, but your library is compiled with a different version of Java to the one you are running.

Comment: the jre is backwards compatible, meaning that a jre version 1.8 will be able to run code compiled with 1.7, but a jre version 1.7 can not run code that is compiled with 1.8. Which version(s) are in conflict here, I 'm not sure, but it's not a problem with syntax of the main method

Comment: yes affectively I think elasticsearch 5.4 must have at least the version 7 and my project work with 1.6 thank u

Comment: Classname is `EsConnectionManagerBiz ` while constructor name is `EsConnection`?